# What's the word for "how noticeable a particular part or pixel of an image is to a human"?

Tags: image-processing

I remember hearing about an algorithm to calculate some property of each pixel of an image which represents how noticeable that pixel is to a human, and so how likely they are to notice if that pixel was modified. I seem to remember the word sounded similar to the word "latency". Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [saliency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salience_(neuroscience)) and in the context of computer vision/image processing [saliency maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saliency_map) provide a measure of this on a per-pixel basis.